# Get the precise screen refresh rate on Windows without DirectX?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, directx, frame-rate

I know of two ways of getting the screen refresh rate on Windows.  The first is the simple `EnumDisplaySettings` function, which fills a struct that contains a rounded screen refresh rate value in fps.  The second is using DirectX, which, during initialization, gives you the option of retrieving the refresh rate by dividing a numerator and a denominator by each other.

From my own experience, the first method is insufficient.  My laptop monitor does not manage to achieve an exact frame rate of 60 - rather, it has multiple settings which border around 59.9 and 60.1 in fps.  The second method gives me an exact floating point value which can be used to achieve the effect of VSync without using VSync directly.

I'm asking this because of the lack of reliable VSync in OpenGL, and I don't want to rely on an extra graphics API at startup only to use it for one small feature.  Is there another way?

Comment: Does knowing the exact fps allow you to vsync? Surely you need to know when the frame starts too.

Comment: That would be yet another issue, but OpenGL is kind of flaky on this either way :/

Comment: I would not blame OpenGL for this, buffer swapping and by extension, VSYNC is actually not even defined by OpenGL. It is ***all*** platform-specific, you can blame WGL and the Win32 API for lack of precision in monitor timing. There is no reason you cannot use DX to get the more precise refresh rate if you want, DX has been an Operating System component since Win95 OSR2 (which is incidentally when OpenGL was introduced as well). Getting the refresh rate is going to be platform-specific no matter how you look at it, so use whatever tools your platform offers.

Comment: And the 59.9 Hz setting you mentioned is probably 59.94 (compatibility timing for the NTSC/ATSC standards). I would not call that exact if it drops the .04 ;) [60 / 1.001, to be ***exact***]

Comment: *Exact* and *floating point value* in the same sentence? Not trying to nitpick here, but if you base your assumptions on floating point values representing exact numbers, you may be in for a disappointment. You will have to deal with rounding errors, and however small they may appear in isolation, they will sum up over time.

Comment: @IInspectable: 60/1.001 is mathematically exact. It's how NTSC works.

Comment: @MSalters I never claimed otherwise. It's just that there is no **floating point value** that represents this exact value. Unless you allow for a floating point format with an infinite mantissa.

Comment: Then again, who cares? 1 frame off in 8 million is once every 38 hours.

Comment: @MSalters You are wrong. It's not **once** in 38 hours. It just means that the frame boundary where the tearing appears (which you were trying to avoid by implementing VSync) will take 38 hours to make it across the screen. It will be there throughout.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Actually I don't get any NTSC rates, I get 60.056.  Is there a standard for that or is it just some random framerate the monitor is capable of?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but laptop LCDs are extremely non-standard. It is not like they ever have to accept an input source other than the GPU that they're hard-wired to. Many standalone LCD panels support 50 Hz (PAL), 59.94 Hz (NTSC) and something pretty close to if not exactly 60.0 Hz. Even so, why are you intent on re-inventing the wheel? Is your problem that you do not like the blocking caused by synchronizing to the display's VBLANK?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I thought the blocking is what VSync did, and my problem was that I can't get VSync to work in OpenGL.  How do I synchronize without an available VSync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on our comments, effectively VSYNC causes blocking... but more accurately, it blocks when the swap-chain is full of back buffers that need to be swapped. Triple buffering can be used to reduce blocking in an implementation of VSYNC, but neither WGL nor GLX exposes arbitrary control over the number of back buffers in the swap-chain, so you have to modify driver settings to enable it in an OpenGL context.

In OpenGL, the GL itself does not handle buffer swaps or VSYNC as I pointed out in an earlier comment, you must use the platform-specific window system layer (e.g. WGL, GLX, AGL/CGL, EGL) to set something known as a **Swap Interval**.

- Setting the swap interval to 1 will enable VSYNC
- Setting the swap interval to 0 will disable VSYNC
- Setting the swap interval to -1 will enable adaptive VSYNC on newer drivers

  <sub>Support is determined by the existence of:</sub>

  `WGL_EXT_swap_control_tear` (Windows)

  or

  `GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear` (Any platform that uses X11, such as Linux)

Adaptive VSYNC is an interesting new feature that blocks if your application is exceeding the display's refresh rate but allows tearing when you are under the refresh rate. This is opposed to the normal behavior where anything below the refresh rate is throttled to some lower factor of the refresh rate.

---

In any case, since you are using Windows in this example, you will want to look into `wglSwapIntervalEXT (...)`.

Comment: I read that wglSwapIntervalEXT doesn't work on newer Windows OSs because the windowing server has complete control over VSync.  That makes it up to the user, which is fine I guess, but I'd prefer there was a way to make sure that it works every time (like any other game programmer, I'd imagine).

Comment: @NmdMystery: In windowed mode this is true, the Desktop Window Manager composites using whatever is in the frontbuffer when ***it*** decides to redraw your window. But this is no different from drawing into a window with D3D or any other graphics API. In fullscreen mode it is a very different story, however. Effectively, in windowed mode with compositing enabled (BTW, you cannot disable this starting with Windows 8) you get free VSYNC whether you want it or not. That said, Windows 8 gets around [some of this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706346(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @NmdMystery: Also note that even though the DWM always prevents tearing, `wglSwapIntervalEXT (...)` still works the way I described in my answer. It can be used to throttle your application to 60 FPS instead of letting it draw at 4000+ FPS. Modern GPUs will throttle the core/memory clocks back when the load is low and setting the swap interval to non-zero is a great way to keep GPU load low. This makes the GPU run cooler/quieter and use less electricity, so the swap interval is useful for more than the prevention of tearing.

Comment: Since I'm using Windows 8, what flags do I need to set when making the window or changing the display settings to enable compositing on all Windows platforms?

Comment: @NmdMystery: Given Windows Vista or 7 you should consult [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969538(v=vs.85).aspx). Anything XP or older does not have a DWM, and in Windows 8 you enable/disable it (it is always on).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't all that much overhead from using DXGI without creating any devices, so it's not nearly as heavy as "Including another API".

It all becomes calls to D3DKMT functions that are exported by GDI32.DLL, and GDI32.DLL is loaded into every process already.